# Getting FB.Event.subscribe implemented satisfactorily

Tags: javascript, facebook, dom-events, facebook-like

I have been trying to make `FB.Event.subscribe` work, but nothing seems to work. Hopefully someone can help me out.

I'm currently using the following:

Html tag

```
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" lang="en-US" xml:lang="en-US" xmlns:fb="http://ogp.me/ns/fb#">
```

After the body tag

```
<body>
<div id="fb-root"></div>
<script>
(function(d, s, id) 
{  
    var js, fjs = d.getElementsByTagName(s)[0];
    if (d.getElementById(id))
        return;
    js = d.createElement(s);
    js.id = id;  js.src = "//connect.facebook.net/en_US/all.js#xfbml=1&appId=153991331310442";     

    fjs.parentNode.insertBefore(js, fjs);
}
(document, 'script', 'facebook-jssdk'));
FB.Event.subscribe('edge.create', function(response) { 
    alert('You liked the URL: ' + response);
});
</script>
```

**FB:Like**

```
<div id="gateway"><fb:like href="http://www.example.com/" send="true" width="450" show_faces="false"></fb:like>
```

Is the `FB.Event.subscribe` supposed to be placed in another area? I tried after the `Fb:Like` code, I tried it as an `onclick` event, but don't seem to get it to work.